# Sympy Solver in a script does not print a return

Tags: python, shell, printing, sympy, solver

I am trying to test out the solver in sympy in a script but cannot get it to print the solution. If I enter line by line in the shell then it works and returns a solution. So why is running the commands in a script different, and what do I need to do to make it work?

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
solve(x**2 - 1, x)
```

Comment: you are not doing anything with the result currently, you just call the function to solve the math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you're missing is to print the solution:

```
print( solve(x**2 - 1, x) )
```

or

```
solution = solve(x**2 - 1, x)
print(solution)
```

The interactive interpreter will always try to evaluate the expressions you enter and print the results back. This does not happen in a script; there, you need to take care of printing yourself.

Comment: wonderful thank you! I originally tried ```print( x )``` assuming x would hold a value but clearly it doesn't

Comment: Glad to have helped & welcome to StackOverflow! As the OP, you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it.